# Apache2 (on Debian) - add password requirement for website

Tags: apache-http-server, password-management

How to add website password requirement for a specific user (Mike)? How to confiqure to ask password on local area network? How to confiqure not to ask password when entering to the website outside from local area network (Mike and others in the internet)?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419592/htaccess-htpasswd-bypass-if-at-a-certain-ip-address